# Как убрать тень у select?

Tags: html, css, html-select, веб-интерфейс

[image: ужасная тень]

```html
<select required>
  <option>Не выбран</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
```

В Интернатах говорят либо [не про то](https://qna.habr.com/q/320392), либо то, что этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: Со стандартными select в целом беда, если нужен какой-то единый кроссбраузерный дизайн - то берём кастомные решения

Comment: Возможности стилизовать выпадающий список у select нету, если очень надо, то используйте другие подходы. Обычно вместо select используют `<div>` + выпадающий список `ul>li` с обработкой из JS.